# Using mongoose to get the distinct values of an object in array for all documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregate, distinct

I'm using Mongoose in nodejs. So here is a sample Publisher model:

```
name: String,
books: [{
    title: String,
    author: {
        name: String,
        age: Number
    }
}]
```

I want to get all the distinct author names that match a regex. I'm new to noSql so maybe I'm just doing something dumb. I figure I want to do something like:

```
Publisher.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$books'},
    {$match: {
        'books.author.name': new RegExp(req.params.regex)
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$books.author.name'
    }},
    {$group: {
        distinctValues: {$addToSet: '$_id'}
    }}
], function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
})
```

This seems like it should work according to: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59661/mongodb-distinct-in-an-array

Any and all input you guys have to help me with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt provide an error you get when performing this query, but it seems you get something like: 'a group specification must include an _id'. 
The issue with your query is here:

```
{$group: {
    distinctValues: {$addToSet: '$_id'}
}}
```

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator MUST include an _id field

So far $group operator provides already distinct group this last pipeline seems redundant, next works for me:

```
Publisher.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$books'},
    {$match: {
        'books.author.name': new RegExp(req.params.regex)
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$books.author.name'
    }}
], function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
})
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. I'm confused though. The values returned seem to be distinct but your change does not specify any requirement on uniqueness. Why is that?

Comment: Thats how $group operator works, you can check the documentation, they have general examples up there (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). From the docs: 'Groups documents by some specified expression and outputs to the next stage a document for each distinct grouping'